# iterate stages with a when directive in a jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a number of projects with a similar build step

```
stage('build component') {
  // build
}
```

If I want to share the step, I can create a list of parameters and iterate over the list outside my build stage.

```
def projects = [
  [
    name: "projectA",
    path: "./path/to/projectA",
  ], [
    name: "projectB",
    path: "./path/to/projectB",
  ]
]

projects.each {
  stage("build ${it.name}") {
    // build with ${it.path}
  }
}
```

I cannot use a `when` directive, however.

```
projects.each {
  stage("build ${it.name}") {
    when { anyOf { changeset "${it.path}" } }
    steps { 
      // build with ${it.path}
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> No such DSL method 'when' found among steps [archive, bat, ...]

I've tried a number of different permutations, including `stage { steps { when {}, script {} } }`. I'm guessing there's a right way to do this, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Where is this code located organizationally? Is this scripted or declarative?

Comment: I cannot use `project.each` outside of a scripted pipeline, so this would have to be scripted for that reason. other than that requirement, it does not need to be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

"when" can't be used in scripted pipeline I guess.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).